# I can't inherit layout_width and height

Tags: android-layout

I'm testing styles in android and I can't seem to inherit the layout_width or height.

This is my styles.xlm in values

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppThemeApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#002AFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppThemeAct" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#002AFF</item>
    </style>
    <style name="stl_button" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#002AFF</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    </style>
    <style name="stl_button.bold">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my layout/main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmd_OpenPlaces"
        style="@style/stl_button.bold"
        android:text="@string/str_cmdOpenPlaces" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/OpenSettings"
        style="@style/stl_button"
        android:text="@string/str_cmdOpenSettings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.programs.squik.myplaces">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditPlacesActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the style for OpenSettings looks fine; however, the one for cmd_OpenPlaces complains about not having the layout_width and height, but this should be inherited from stl_button.

I get this

```
<Button> does not set the required layout_heigth attribute...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: It's not complaining anything I have tested your code.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add the manifest and since you said it didn't give you problem I went and fiddled with it and apparently my problem is the name of the theme. It won't take AppThemeApp. It has to be AppTheme. Now the question is how can i have multiple themes defined and use any of them? I feel I'm still missing something. I should be able to define multiple theme.

Comment: create theme as you created AppThemeApp and AppThemeAct and set it's theme in activity tag in manifest. or you can also setTheme programmatically . You can associate one theme to an Activity at a time. And also make sure the theme you created suit's your activity. as some activity needs actionBar then don't use any theme without actionBar

Answer (score 0):

Well I figure my problem.

The android studio editor has a tool on the layout design view that associates the layout with a theme regardless of what I have in the manifest and it also validates the layout's xml against the theme assigned to it.

That's why it gave errors; however, once I install and ran the app it worked out fine. It also explains why the layout design would not change according to what I set on the manifest.